# Unable to prove a relation which Stirling Numbers of 2nd kind must satisfy

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

I am trying exercises of Richard Brualdi Introductory Combinatorics and I am unable to think about this question in exercise of Chapter 8 .

> Prove that Stirling numbers of 2nd Kind satisfy S(n, n-2) = ${n \choose 3 } + 3{n \choose 4 } $ . for n$\geq$2 .
>
> I am trying to use Combinatorial definition by which Stirling numbers of 2nd kind S(p,k)equals  no. Of partition of p objects into k indistinguishable boxes so that no box remain empty.
> Using that in case no. box is empty and 1 box contain 3objects I can get the term 4*   ${n \choose 3 } $  but how to obtain the other term. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a partition of $n$ (distinguishable) objects into $n-2$ (indistinguishable) subsets, two cases are possible:

1. We have a subset consisting of $3$ objects, and all other subsets contain $1$ object each. The number of such partitions is equal to the number of ways to select those $3$ objects, which is equal to $\binom{n}{3}$.
2. We have two subsets consisting of $2$ objects each, and all other subsets contain $1$ object each. The number of such partitions is equal to the number of ways to select $4$ objects [equal to $\binom{n}{4}$] multiplied by the number of ways to make $2$ pairs out of these $4$ objects [equal to $3$].